# XCode CoreData Indexing Issue

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I have been working along with a project with no issues for a month, and yesterday I added CoreData to the mix.  My XCode project started acting up, I could not get the code sense or coloring to work right and indexing was taking forever.  I am able to get it to index if I delete the derived data and also delete the xcworkspace file and xcuserdata from my project, but once I re-open the project and choose to run on the device it hangs indexing again.

If I remove the CoreData from the pch file, it indexes with no problems, even with the device picked in the list.  But once I re-add CoreData to my pch, it stops working.

What could cause this?

I am on XCode 5.0.2 on Mavericks

It seems that anywhere I import CoreData causes this issue, I even started a fresh project, and it hangs in the same way.

Here is how I am importing it:

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
```

Even when i start a brand now project with CoreData it refuses to index, I am re-installing XCode...

Comment: Are you including the CoreData framework in your build settings?

Comment: Yes, no problems there. The project builds and runs fine, just won't index!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the solution was to re-install XCode...what a pain, but it got the job done.